# Define unique key strongloop model

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

How can i make the Unique key as a combination of 3 columns in loopback model 
The model structure is like

```
"properties": {
"year": {
  "type": "number",
  "required": true
},
"user_id": {
  "type": "number",
  "required": true
},
"leave_type_id": {
  "type": "number",
  "required": true
},
"total_days": {
  "type": "number",
  "required": true
}
```

},

And for me the year,User_id,leave_type_id  combination is going to be a unique key . How can i mention that in the loop back model definition

Answer (score 4):

Define multiple `id` properties on the field.

```
...
"user_id": {
  "id": 1, //add this
  "type": "number",
  "required": true
},
"leave_type_id": {
  "id": 2, //add this
  "type": "number",
  "required": true
},
...
```

See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-CompositeIDs